# Is it an issue for background checks, if my previous employer has closed?

Tags: software-industry, india

I have total 4 years of experience and so far I have changed organization twice.
Until recently, I have been working at a Company A, however I have resigned due to personal reasons.

I have received an offer from another company, Company B, but have heard they have a very strict background verification check.

My worry is that Company A is going to close next month, and that it may cause problems for the background checks. I do however, have a copy of all the relevant documents from that (soon to be closed) Company A.

Should I expect this to be a problem, and if so - what steps can I take to mitigate this?

Comment: What is CTS? What is TCS? I’d suggest to think about what you’re posting and make things clear.

Comment: @gnashaer729, i am new for this sites and i think we can ask this kind of questions in this site and i am very clearly exploring above what i asked

Comment: Do not post company names here

Comment: Acronyms/TLAs are a really bad idea, don't summarise, be specific.  I understand thanks to your clarifications that CTS and TCS are two different companies, yes?  (Rather than naming them, using "Company A" and "Company B".).  Have you resigned your position from Company A - and what are you worried about with regard to the background checks from Company B?  Is Company A going under and that is why you are leaving?

Comment: No i already resigned in Company A and joined into Company B but Company A going to close next 1 month so is this problem in Background versification ?

Comment: I edited my question please check once

Comment: I think it is clearer without company names, and seems as though it would be better for OP in case they don't want to be identified

Answer (score 5):

I won't comment specifically on the company, as I don't believe this is necessary, but more broadly:

**This happens all the time.**

Background checks can be really thorough going back ten years or more. Lots of people will have worked for start ups and alike which have gone under, non of them would be able to be verified if it was a problem.

Two things for you to do if you're really worried:

1. Contact company B and just explain that company A will be closing and ask if that is going to be an issue and if there is anything you can do to steam-line. For example, if there is any specific documentation required from company A.
2. Company A must know you're leaving if they are closing - ask for paperwork. I would suggest a letter of recommendation - which will also double as proof of employment. Ensure you have a copy of your contract etc. too. It might be a good idea to get your managers contact info, the company who does the vetting for company B will probably ask.

Answer (score 1):

### No, I don't expect it will cause any problems for your background check.

The same thing happened to me, and I had no issues with my background check for the US Department of Defense.  I'm sure it happens all the time.

Comment: Agreed. I worked at a small department store as a kid that closed down. I don't even remember how to spell my manager's name except phonetically. I don't even know if the store is operating anywhere or what their central HQ is. I just included it in the paper and mentioned the points. No issues at all.

Comment: The OP is from India. Do you know if your experience with American background check processes would generalise internationally like that?

Comment: @nick012000 yes, I believe it does.  Especially when you consider how commonplace it is for businesses to go under.

Comment: @Lumberjack I think that the answer might be improved if you explain why you think it universalizes like that. Different countries have different rules, and they adhere to them to varying degrees, after all.

Answer (score 1):

Companies close all of the time. This isn't your fault. This is not a reflection on you.

I would assume that the new company would assume that you were truthful, even if they can't verify your work at your former company. At worst they might ask you for additional contact information for someone at your former company who can provide a reference and work history on your behalf.